# Django register filter not working

Tags: django-templates, django-template-filters

I have a special filter so that I can check user permissions in my Django templates, but I keep getting the error that I'm using an invalid filter.

Views.py looks like this:

```
from django import template
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group
register = template.Library()

@register.filter(name='has_group') 
def has_group(user, group_name): 
  group = Group.objects.get(name=group_name) 
  return True if group in user.groups.all() else False
```

Then in my template I have this:

```
{% if request.user|has_group:"MOM" %} 
  <p>User belongs to my group </p>
{% else %} 
  <p>User doesn't belong to MOM</p> 
{% endif %}
```

Why am I getting an invalid filter error?

Answer (score 0):

you have to load the template tags, before you could use them.

you do that by adding this line `{% load template_tags %}` before calling the template tag !!